# Run Phpunit and JS test simultaneous via CircleCI

Tags: testing, parallel-processing, continuous-integration, circleci

I use circle to run JS and PHP test (Protractor/ Phpunit).

I would like use parallelism to win time but i don't know configure the parallelism. I activate the parallelism in the circle parameters (2 containers).

My actual circle configuration (circle.yml) :

```
# Depend de app/config/parameters.circle.yml (parametre symfony pour circle) et app/config/apache.circle (configuration d'Apache pour Circle)

# Configuration du serveur
machine:
    php:
        version: 5.4.21
    timezone:
        Europe/Paris
    hosts:
        bluegrey.circle.dev: 127.0.0.1

dependencies:
    pre:
        # SauceConnect (Angular)
        - wget https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-latest-linux.tar.gz
        - tar -xzf sc-latest-linux.tar.gz
        - ./bin/sc -u johnnyEvo -k xxx:
            background: true
            pwd: sc-*-linux
        # Installation protractor (Angular)
        - npm install -g protractor
        # On active XDebug
        - sed -i 's/^;//' ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv global)/etc/conf.d/xdebug.ini
        - echo "xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250" > ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv global)/etc/conf.d/xdebug.ini
        # Configuration d'Apache
        - cp app/config/apache.circle /etc/apache2/sites-available
        - a2ensite apache.circle
        - sudo service apache2 restart
    override:
        # Composer
        - composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction
    post:
        # Assets
        - app/console assetic:dump
        # Parameters
        - cp app/config/parameters.circle.yml.dist app/config/parameters.yml

database:
    pre:
        # Base de données (test)
        - app/console doctrine:database:create --env=test --no-interaction
        - app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test --no-interaction
        # Base de données (prod/ angular)
        - app/console doctrine:database:drop --no-interaction --force
        - app/console doctrine:database:create --no-interaction
        - app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --no-interaction
        # Fixture
        - app/console doctrine:fixture:load --no-interaction


test:
    pre:
        # Permission pour que Protractor puisse naviguer le site
        - sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs app/sessions
        - sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs app/sessions
    override:
        - php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/phpunit -c app
        - protractor angutest
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm one of the CircleCI devs.

the most straightforward way is to run the PHP tests on one container and the JS tests on another, if they have approximately similar runtimes then you'll get the benefit without having to manually split test suites.

Something like the following would work in that case:

```
test:
  override:
    - case $CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX in 0) php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/phpunit -c app ;; 1) protractor angutest ;; esac:
        parallel: true
```

Comment: It should also be parallel to the apache configuration and write permission and It Works! thank you :)